# Transparent windows on resize in Microsoft Edge

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

Micosoft Edge is factory installed on both my home and work PCs in favor of Internet Explorer, which appears to be deprecated.  When I resize Edge, the resized portion of the window becomes transparent.  At home and at work. This bug has apparently been [around for years](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2026975-when-i-resize-edge-larger-in-win10-resized-area-is-transparent).  I've Googled and I can't find a fix. It's not my drivers because the same thing happens on two Windows 10 installs, one Pro and one Home, on entirely different computers. Does anybody know the status of this?  Why is Microsoft jamming this buggy browser but leaving it in this broken state?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue in my Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0. The window renders well when I resize Edge. What's the version of Microsoft Edge you use? You can update to the latest version and try it again.

Comment: I can't find any kind of About button in Edge so it's not easy to find the version.  Going into Add/Remove programs, it seems to be 44.17763.1.0.  I also have 3 GPUs on my system, so that might be a problem.  I have the Intel integrated graphics and two NVidia GPUs.  But that doesn't explain it entirely because my work computer is a little Dell shoebox with no NVidia GPU and it does the same thing.

Comment: You can check your Edge version like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j66Yc.gif . You're using the older version of Edge, please move to the latest version and try again.

Comment: It's not just the browser, it's the Settings app, OneNote, Microsoft Store, Mail, Calendar, Microsoft To Do. Why? Apparently, it doesn't bother MS. I'd say 50% chance they'll fix this in 5 years time.